# Should we render react component at multiple places?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

So, i have component called Balance component which i want to display in navbar and on a page (summary page) component as well.

But i want to prevent it from making an api request twice.

The code of balanceSlice:

```
import {createSlice, createAsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const updateBalance = createAsyncThunk(
  'balance/fetchBalance',
  async () => {
    const response = await fetchBalance();
    return response.data;
  }
);

const initialState = {
    value: 0
};

export const balanceSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'balance',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
    },
    extraReducers: () => {...}
});

export const selectBalance = (state) => state.balance.value;

export default balanceSlice.reducer;
```

Here is the code of Balance

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from 'react-redux';

import {updateBalance, selectBalance} from './balanceSlice';


function Balance() {
    const balance = useSelector(selectBalance);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();


    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(updateBalance());
      console.log('component ran')
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <>
          {balance}  
        </>
    );
}

export default Balance;
```

As i want to reuse this component at multiple places, so i haven't added any styling in this component. The styling is being done in summary page and the navbar. The updateBalance is requesting new balance from the api. I am using redux toolkit and I am trying to follow single responsibility principle and making component small, reusable and testable.

Is it recommended to render balance component at multiple places?
Navbar code:

```
import Balance from './../../features/balance/Balance';
    function TopNavbar() {
    return (
    <Navbar>
    <span className={styles.navbar__text__span}><Balance /></span>
    </Navbar>
    );
    }
```

Similarly, i am importing Balance component in summaryPage component and rendering it. Is it a recommended approach or should i simply import selectBalance from balanceSlice and display it in navbar?

Comment: if you only want to reuse those methods `e.g. updateBalance` in multiple places then you can create a custom hook instead of component.

Comment: @miraj, i just want to display it at multiple place. Currently, i am displaying it in navbar and at summary page. Next, i might display it again in left menu on mobile devices. I want to make updateBalance request only once

Comment: then you can call the api on a parent component. bcz `<Balance />` will call the API each place where it will be rendered

Comment: Thats possible but it breaks the single responsibility principle.  As redux toolkit demonstrated that api usage should be done from balanceSlice

Comment: You can use the context or redux for this purpose. In case you use redux, you can store the current state relating balance which can have value fetching, fetched and ready. Check the current state of the store and you set the state fetching and make the api call only when state is ready.

Comment: @TopW3, this is how it is working. Redux toolkit is a new way doung this in a cleaner way. But my question is, should i render to Balance components on a page (on the navbar and in summay page) or should i just fetch the balance value from the store in summaryPage and display the value? If i go with the second option, there would be no problem of rendering but is it the right approach? The first option is making 2 api calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render Balance components wherever you need.
Balance component would look like this.

```
function Balance() {
    const balance = useSelector(selectBalance);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        if (balance.status === 'ready') {
            dispatch(updateBalance());
        }
        console.log('component ran')
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <>
            {balance.value ?? 0}
        </>
    );
}
```

In updateBalance action, you should set the balance status to 'fetching' and call the api. After api call is finished, you can set the balance status to 'fetched' and set the balance value to the fetched value. That's all I guess.